# Referring to a specific symbol in a static library with the GNU gold linker

Tags: linker, ld, binutils, linker-scripts, gold-linker

When laying out symbols in the address space using a linker script, `ld` allows to
refer to a specific symbol coming from a static library with the following
syntax:

```
archive.a:object_file.o(.section.symbol_name)
```

Using `gold` rather than `ld`, it seems that such a directive is ignored. The 
linking process succeeds. However, when using this instruction to put a specific
symbol at a specific location with `gold` and checking the resulting symbol layout
using `nm` or having a look at the Map file, the symbol is not in the expected 
location.

I made a small test case using a dummy hello world program statically compiled 
in its entrety with gcc 5.4.0. The C library is musl libc (last commit on the 
master branch from the official git repository). For binutils, I also use the 
last commit on the master branch from the official git repository.

I use the linker script to place a specific symbol (`.text.exit`) from a static 
library (musl C library: `libc.a`) at a specific location in the address space 
which is: the first position in the `.text` section.

My linker script is:

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10000;
    .text :
    {
        /* Forcing .text.exit in the first position in .text section */
        musl/lib/libc.a:exit.o(.text.exit);
        *(.text*);
    }
    . = 0x8000000;
    .data : { *(.data*) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) }
    .bss : { *(.bss*) }
}
```

My Makefile:

```
# Set this to 1 to link with gold, 0 to link with ld
GOLD=1

SRC=test.c
OBJ=test.o
LIBS=musl/lib/crt1.o \
    musl/lib/libc.a \
    musl/lib/crtn.o
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-nostdinc -I musl/include -I musl/obj/include
BIN=test
LDFLAGS=-static
SCRIPT=linker-script.x
MAP=map

ifeq ($(GOLD), 1)
LD=binutils-gdb/gold/ld-new
else
LD=binutils-gdb/ld/ld-new
endif

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC) -o $(OBJ)
    $(LD) --output $(BIN) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) -T $(SCRIPT) \
        -Map $(MAP)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) $(BIN) $(MAP)
```

After compiling and linking I'm checking the map file (obtained using the -Map 
`ld`/`gold` flag) to have a look at the location of `.text.exit`. Using `ld` as the 
linker, it is indeed in the first position of the text section. Using `gold`, it 
is not (it is present farther in the address space, as if my directive was not 
taken into account).

Now, while neither of these work with `gold`:

```
musl/lib/libc.a:exit.o(.text.exit);
musl/lib/libc.a(.text.exit)
```

This works:

```
*(.text.exit);
```

Is that a missing feature in `gold`? or am I doing something wrong, maybe there is
another way to refer to a specific symbol of a specific object file in an 
archive using `gold`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When laying out symbols in the address space using a linker script, ld allows to
>   refer to a specific symbol coming from a specific object file inside a static
>   library with the following syntax:
>
> archive.a:object_file.o(.section.symbol_name)

That isn't quite what that syntax means. When you see
".section.symbol_name" in the linker script (or in a readelf or
objdump list of sections), that is the whole name of the section, and
you'll only see sections with names like that if you use the
-ffunction-sections option when compiling. Given that your script
works with ld, and if you just use the full filename wild card with
gold, it looks like your musl libraries were indeed compiled with
-ffunction-sections, but that's not something you can always assume is
true for system libraries. So the linker isn't really searching for a
section named ".text" that defines a symbol named "exit" -- instead,
it's simply looking for a section named ".text.exit". Subtle
difference, but you should be aware of it.

> Now, while neither of these work with gold:
>   musl/lib/libc.a:exit.o(.text.exit);
>   musl/lib/libc.a(.text.exit);
>
> This works:
>   *(.text.exit);
>
> Is that a missing feature in gold? or am I doing something wrong, maybe there is
>   another way to refer to a specific symbol of a specific object file in an
>   archive using gold?

If you look at the resulting -Map output file, I suspect you'll see
the name of the object file is written as "musl/lib/libc.a(exit.o)".
That's the spelling you need to use in the script, and because of the
parentheses, you need to quote it. This:

```
"musl/lib/libc.a(exit.o)"(.text.exit)
```

should work. If you want something that will work in both linkers, try
something like this:

```
"musl/lib/libc.a*exit.o*"(.text.exit)
```

or just

```
"*exit.o*"(.text.exit)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the syntax using quotes worked. I also checked musl compile flags and, indeed, these include -ffunction-sections.